# Как управлять мышью ,а не курсором

Tags: c#

Нужно глобально отслеживать и посылать движение и нажатие мыши и клавиатуры,чтобы программа управляла мышью абсолютно везде.Проблема в том что когда я использовал WinApi ,аля, "SetCursorPos" из Win32 то в какой нибудь игре камера игрока стоит на месте,а не перемещается,то есть эти функции управляют конкретно курсором.
А как сделать чтоб мы могли "эмулировать" движение мыши,и она перемещалась по координатам везде?

Comment: По заголовку мне сразу представилась функция RealMouseMove двигающая мышку по коврику... Отхожу от компьютера и опа опа поползла мышка.

Comment: Саму мышку надо запереть внутри окна Считывать не её положение, а движение курсора diffX diffY.

Comment: А можно чуть поподробнее?...Когда я управлял курсором SetCursorPos user32.dll игровая камера стояла на месте,но курсор в менюшке двигался...

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/inputdev/using-raw-input?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Тогда покажите код. Каким образом эмулировали движение мыши. Была ли игра (что за игра, кстати?) в полноэкранном режиме или нет?